# How can i order my SQL Results if one column is empty?

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding ordering the results of my query.
I have 3 columns which needs ordering:

```
ORDER BY level DESC, logo DESC, bName ASC
```

I'd like to order highest 'level' first by DESC, which works.

After that i'd like to order if 'logo' is empty or not, but not ordering the content of logo which my query does.

And last i'd like to order by bName ASC

So my disired output would be like:

```
1. Level-3 has logo bName a-z
2. Level-3 has no Logo bName a-z
3. Level-2 has logo bName a-z
4. Level-2 has no Logo bName a-z
5. Level-1 has logo bName a-z
6. Level-1 has no Logo bName a-z
```

Is it possible to do this with just one clean query?

**Corresponding sample input:**

| level | logo | bName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | test.jpg | Testname |
| 2 |  | Testname |
| 1 | 12test.jpg | Another Testname |
| 1 | 3test.jpg | Jane Doe |
| 2 |  | John Doe |
| 2 |  | Dodo Doe |
| 3 | 5test.jpg | Testname |
| 1 | sdsd-test.jpg | Testname |

column logo is just empty in some cases ( e.g. = '' ) but not NULL

Comment: Use a *case expression*

Comment: Please also include the corresponding sample input, as _text_, in a table.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided information as to the data and what "logo is empty" actually means however the principle is:

```
ORDER BY 
  level DESC, 
  case when logo <> '' then 1 else 2 end,
  bName ASC;
```

Comment: i'm sorry, i have edited my post providing some sample data of how the database looks. column logo is just empty in some cases ( e.g. = '' ) but not NULL

Comment: Seems to work nice. Could you explain it a bit for me for further understandings? i assume it first order by level DESC then checks if logo is empty or not and the ones not empty are ordered "1" and the ones empty ordered "2" and finally orders to bname Asc? Did i understand it correct?

Comment: @tvaqsct your description is correct, each successive argument in the order by acts as a tie-breaker for the preceding one, so in the event of duplicate Levels they are then sorted by the result of the case expression etc